# Lambdas and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, c++11

I've recently started using lambdas an awful lot within threads, and want to make sure I'm not setting myself up for thread-safety issues/crashes later. My usual way of using them is:

```
class SomeClass {  
    int someid;  
    void NextCommand();  
    std::function<void(int, int)> StoreNumbers;  
    SomeClass(id, fn); // constructor sets id and storenumbers fn  
}

// Called from multiple threads  
static void read_callback(int fd, void* ptr)  
{  
    SomeClass* sc = static_cast<SomeClass*>ptr;  
    ..  
    sc->StoreNumbers(someint,someotherint); // voila, thread specific storage.  
}  

static DWORD WINAPI ThreadFn(LPVOID param)  
{  
    std::list<int> ints1;  
    std::list<int> ints2;  
    auto storenumbers = [&] (int i, int i2) {  
        // thread specific lambda.  
        ints1.push_back(i);  
        ints2.push_back(i2);  
        };  
    SomeClass s(id, storenumbers);  
    ...  
    // set up something that eventually calls read_callback with s set as the ptr. 
}
```

ThreadFn is used as the thread function for 30-40 threads.

Is this acceptable? I usually have a few of these thread-specific lambdas that operate on a bunch of thread specific data.

Thank you!

Comment: http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com ?

Comment: Not really, that's not "real" code (I wrote it in notepad in around 2 minutes with no error checking, and it shows). I'm asking more about the general idea of using lambdas in this manner, rather than the code itself.

Comment: I am new too, so just curious to know that what is the `return` value of the lambda function ?

Comment: My pardon, but what is the purpose of this code? If you need thread local memory storage then you can use something like thread alloc/new of Konstantin Knizhnik: http://garret.ru/threadalloc/readme.html 
Could you elaborate more on the task you are trying to solve?
It is just not clear why do you need lambdas there. 
Lambdas can be useful in thread programming though, for example: 
http://www.terrainformatica.com/2011/01/c0x-running-code-in-gui-thread-from-worker-threads/

Comment: @c-smile: the read_callback is the callback function used when there's data to read from the network (async). Some data is read from the network, and then then lambdas are used to update the state of the thread.

Comment: @Robert Stone: still not clear, how exactly async read is implemented in your case? It could be a) completion ports - in this case you should have synchronization primitives or 2) blocking read/write - in  this case you don't need any callbacks at all. So asking...

Comment: @Robert Stone: The select function blocks the calling process until there is activity on any of the specified sets of file descriptors, or until the timeout period has expired. So it blocks your thread and immediately after it you can read data from socket[s] to your `std::list<int> ints1;`. Where these callback come from? And so your lambdas.

Comment: @c-simile: Multiple threads running multiple select loops using a single callback function (libev(ent)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem here. A data access with a lambda is no different to a data access with a named function, through inline code, a traditional functor, one made with `bind`, or any other way. As long as that lambda is invoked from only one thread at a time, I don't see any evidence of thread-related problems.